# Switch Or Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ethernet, switch

I have just finished wiring my house with Cat5 cabling, and all keystone jacks added etc.  My "server room" is downstairs in my 2 story home, I will be making 6 runs with wall fishes to rooms upstairs.

Question at hand is - to connect my router downstairs to the 6 wall fishes upstairs should I

1) Run 1 cable to a secondary 8 port router upstairs and from each port in the router run a cable to the wall fishes--> benefit I get a wireless signal upstairs as well as can connect the Cat5 to each room

2) Run 1 cable to a secondary 4 port router then 1 cable to a switch.  From the switch run the cabling to each room upstairs.

Will the switch really benefit me in this instance?  Is it needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fewer pieces of equipment involved, the lower latency and fewer potential problems to diagnose.

Without a diagram of your setup, I would recommend you connect all of your Ethernet runs with a switch.  From there you could add additional hardware needed after the jack.  You don't need additional routing performed beyond your first router/modem, you just need everything to be connected.

The only additional piece of hardware you may require should be a Wi-Fi repeater, or a device configured specifically to that task.  Or in the event that you need more than one Ethernet connected device in a room with only one jack, an additional switch.

To recap:  Run your router into a 7-port-or-greater switch, and the switch to your wall outlets.